# Vue Js Linking pages is not displaying anything

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-cli

I am trying to link pages together in my Vue application and it is not displaying anything.

I am not using vue-router but a a method in which I define my pages in a vue.config.js in my project folder. My pages sit under src/pages/'page name' and inside that sits a app.vue and also a main.js. Refer to the below for screenshots.

When navigating to a page i have defined, the title appears correctly but nothing is displayed. I have a complete blank page.

I am seeking help as to why this is happening. Thank you in advance!

Here are 2 screenshots of things i think are important.

[Layout of my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPoUB.png)

[Vue.Config.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcd3w.png)

This is my App.vue located in src/pages/HomePage/App.vue

```vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img
      alt="Vue logo"
      src="@/assets/logo.png"
    >

    <div style="position: relative">
      <div class="short-it">
      </div>

      <div />
    </div>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Go to</li>

        <li>
          <a
            href="about.html"
          >
            About Us
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.short-it {
  position: relative;

  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 300px;

}

nav ul {
  margin-top: 30px
}
</style>
```

This is my main.js located in src/pages/HomePage/main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Below are further screenshots and snippets of files that i thought i might just include.

This is Jsconfig.json file located in jsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  }
}
```

Below is my package.json located in package.json

```json
{
  "name": "brayden-dk",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "scss-loader": "^0.0.1",
    "vue": "^3.2.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {
      "vue/multi-word-component-names": "off"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new Vue app for every page?

Comment: I found a tutorial using this method. Vue-Router seemed incredibly complex. This is my first time using view hence the idiocracy xD

Comment: Okay, since this is your first time with Vue: just stick with vue-router, don't try to reinvent the wheel. It is the standard way to use routing in vue and it works great. What you are doing now is ruining the benefits of building a Single Page Application. Just look up some introduction tutorials on Vue3, Vite, Vue-router and maybe Pinia on YouTube or Udemy to get you started.

Comment: Yea. Good idea. I did some tutorials on Vue-Router and is working fine.

Comment: Only reason i did that was because i was struggling with vue router and saw that solution.